# How can I let my function reverse everything that's printed on a file WITHOUT using import?

Tags: python, function, file, reverse

Write a function reverse(filename:str) -> str that reads data from a given filename and returns the reverse of the file content. Your function should ignore the following characters ' ', '\r', '\n', '\t'. For example, supposed there is a file called test.txt with the following content:

```
a b c
   d e
 f g
```

**assert reverse('test.txt') == 'gfedcba'**

I have solved the question, but it requires import like this...

```
import re
def reverse(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as write_reversed:
        content = write_reversed.read()
    return re.sub(r"\n|\s|\t", "", "".join(reversed(content)))
```

How can I do it without using import?

Comment: you are using ``re`` only to replace the whitespaces, correct? Then simply chain some ``str.replace`` together to do the same.

Comment: @MikeScotty so basically just write str.replace(r"\n|\s|\t", "", "".join(reversed(content)))??

Comment: Can you think of a rule that tells you the first character that you should output? Can you think of a process that lets you figure that out? Maybe something that looks at each character of the string one at a time? Which end should you start from? Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [str.maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) and [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) accordingly:

```
reversed_content = content[::-1]
# Table to remove all \n\r\t and space.
translation_table = str.maketrans("", "", "\n\r\t ")
result = reversed_content.translate(translation_table)
```

---

Full solution:

```
def reverse(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as write_reversed:
        content = write_reversed.read()
    return content.translate(str.maketrans("", "", "\n\r\t "))[::-1]
```

Much faster than multiple `str.replace` calls, and is quite clean.